# Show profile picture but don't show if account doesn't exist

Tags: javascript, jquery, javascript-security

I'm currently coding an intranet which is also accessible by the internet. With jQuery I managed that when the user types his email in the login screen, jQuery requests a PHP page (e.g. picture.php?u=username) and his profile picture appears, so he can check his. How can I prevent that a hacker directly calls my `picture.php` with all possible emails and checks if they exist? Should I delete this feature?

Comment: Try to read about HTTP POST/GET methods and their differences

Comment: Shouldn't there be some kind of authentication for users, e.g., some kind of login?

Comment: On the server side, verify that the person is who they say they are through some password that they have to set up.

Comment: you can never rely on `javascript`/`jQuery` alone in terms of security management. `javascript` is processed on the clientside and thus readable for everyone. that's why security-relevant methods should always be done by serverside code like `PHP`.

Comment: The picture appears on the login page. I only wanted to provide a more comfortable way to verify his input and check the email server-side and then display his username and profile picture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could return a picture (in the php page) of a random user when the email does not exist so that the hacker can't see if an account with that email address exists.

Comment: Good idea! Do you think I can also return a standard profile icon?

Comment: @DevTec the hacker could compare the returned picture with the standard picture and decide that he's just going to assume that every account with the standard icon does not exist

Comment: If I add a watermark with PHP e.G. return a white picture with a randomly generated white text on it, can the Hacker compare it? Should the text be lite-gray? Another idea: Can returning a randomly generated pattern with different colors help?

Comment: @DevTec yes that would work too, although I think it would be easier to code if you showed a random user's picture because then you don't need to generate an image in php

Answer (score 0):

When the user logins into his/her account, the application should generate a random token and store it in the session. Whenever any form is displayed to the user, the token should be present in the page as a hidden input field. Application logic must check for the token and ensure that it matches the token present in the session. If no match is found that means someone is trying to access the url from outside of the application and you can simply exit from the script.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I wanted to display the picture at the login page. But I'll keep your answer in mind.